# REBOL Change the backdrop image and text

Tags: rebol

REBOL
I currently trying to redo a small app I made in Delphi.
This application displays a background image among n and a text among n, but I cannot change the image or the text, the change of image and text is done by the button >>.

This is the simplified code without the random part because I found out about it:

```
Rebol[
Title: "You have a message !"
Version: 1.0.0
Needs: [1.2.115]
]

the-imag1: load %"/C/MyFile/Cours CD/Affiche/Images/Vague9.jpg"
the-imag2: load %"/C/MyFile/Cours CD/Affiche/Images/Vague3.jpg"
the-image: the-imag1
text1: "Your banner text here" 

view xx1: layout [
size the-image/size
b1: backdrop the-image

at b1/offset + 110x120
box  350x150 font-size 20 font-color black [align: 'center] text1

    at b1/offset + 530x370
    btn ">>" [the-image: the-imag2 ; new image
              text1: "Hello"       ; new text
               show xx1] effect [multiply 90]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redefining the face, not just the content. Just redefine the field you need. Try this:

```
Rebol[
    Title: "You have a message !"
    Version: 1.0.0
    Needs: [1.2.115]
]

the-imag1: load %"/C/MyFile/Cours CD/Affiche/Images/Vague9.jpg"
the-imag2: load %"/C/MyFile/Cours CD/Affiche/Images/Vague3.jpg"
the-image: the-imag1
text1: "Your banner text here" 

view xx1: layout [
size the-image/size
b1: backdrop the-image

at b1/offset + 110x120
t1: text text1

    at b1/offset + 530x370
    btn ">>" [
        b1/image: the-imag2       ; new image
        t1/text: "Hello"       ; new text
        show xx1
    ] effect [multiply 90]
]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, except I have changed : text1/text by b1/text. But I have noticed that the new text appears behind the first one when it should replace it. Probably it is the same thing with the image, piling up above the first one... What can be done to avoid this ?

Comment: Ah, my fault, I thought that **text1** is text face. You should add name for your text face (for example **text-face: text1**) and then you can change the text using **text-face/text: "Hello"**.

If you set the text in **b1/text** than you're setting the text to the background (see **b1: backdrop the-image**), that's why it's behind the first one.

Comment: Ok, but I have changed because I am getting this error with text1/text : ** Script Error: Invalid path value: text
** Where: func [face value][b1/image: the-imag1
    text1/text: "coucou"
    show xx1
]
** Near: text1/text: "coucou"
show xx1
>>

Comment: I am still mixed up, because I have always an error. Could you correct the code ? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I was doing the edit by the hand, it was missing **text** style. Latest edit should be fine.